# Readonly vs disabled what wrong from my code?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

`Readonly` vs `disabled` what wrong from my code?

```
  <select id="A" onchange="change_val(A,B)">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
    </select>

<input type="text" id="B" value="Hello first time"/>


function change_val(selectbox,input_filed) {
  var sel = document.getElementById(selectbox),
  lbl = document.getElementById(input_filed);

  lbl.disabled = (sel.selectedIndex !== 0);
  if(sel.selectedIndex === 0) {
  lbl.value = 'Hello first time';
  } else {
  lbl.value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
  }
}
```

This script works fine with "DISABLED" input  Attribute when we changed select box.
BUT When I try for `READONLY`input  Attribute Because I need the data  submitted but not allow to changed
So I changed the function look like this:

```
function change_val(selectbox,input_filed) {
  var sel = document.getElementById(selectbox),
  lbl = document.getElementById(input_filed);
if(sel.selectedIndex !== 0){var readonly='readonly';}
  lbl.readonly = readonly;
  if(sel.selectedIndex === 0) {
  lbl.value = 'Hello first time';
  } else {
  lbl.value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
  }
}
```

The `READONLY` input field does not works.input field `still editable`

Anybody have an idea what is the problems with the code? What is my misunderstanding for readonly attribute?

Comment: *The READONLY input field does not works.* What does that mean? What *does not work*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute is called `readOnly` (capital O):

```
lbl.readOnly = (sel.selectedIndex !== 0);
```

You should also pass strings to the function:

```
<select id="A" onchange="change_val('A','B')">
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ueqqx/)

Answer (score 1):

Your casing is wrong and I believe it should be a boolean value.

```
lbl.readOnly = true;
```

Edit: Having reviewed the DOM I don't think there is actually a `readOnly` property on the `<select>` element.  Can't you hide the actual select and simply show a read only text box instead?